# Deriving a Rayleigh distribution

Tags: probability-or-statistics, distributions

When I tried to find this Rayleigh distribution *Mathematica* couldn't come with an answer:

```
PDF[TransformedDistribution[
  Sqrt[x1^2 + x2^2], {x1 \[Distributed] 
    NormalDistribution[μ1, σ], 
   x2 \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[μ2, σ]}, 
  Assumptions -> μ1 == μ2 == 0], r]
```

I want to derive the Rayleigh distribution in parametric form.
Mathematica could solve this for N~[0,1] and the answer is Rayleigh[1],
but for N~[0,k] it has no answer.

Comment: Why not to use the [`RayleighDistribution`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RayleighDistribution.html)?

Comment: Well, computer algebra systems can't solve every problem you throw at them.  Questions like "why can't Mathematica solve it" are not a very good fit here usually.  If the question is "how to compute this", then the anwser is what m0nhawk said.

Comment: @Szabolcs My shrink used to answer all my questions like that.

Comment: @OP What is your question?

Comment: My Question is how Can I Solve this using Mathematica

Mathematica Solve this Problem for Normal Distribution ~ [0,1]
and returns RayleighDistribution[1] but for Normal Distribution~[0,k]
has no Answer!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `BinormalDistribution` instead of two univariate normal distributions:

```
TransformedDistribution[Sqrt[x1^2 + x2^2],
 {x1, x2} ~Distributed~ BinormalDistribution[{0, 0}, {σ, σ}, 0]]
(* RayleighDistribution[σ] *)

TransformedDistribution[Sqrt[x1^2 + x2^2],
  {x1, x2} ~Distributed~ BinormalDistribution[{m, m}, {σ, σ}, 0]]
(* RiceDistribution[Sqrt[2] m, σ] *)

TransformedDistribution[Sqrt[x1^2 + x2^2],
 {x1, x2 } ~Distributed~ BinormalDistribution[{m1, m2}, {σ1, σ2}, 0]]
(* BeckmannDistribution[m1, m2, σ1, σ2, 0] *)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Simon! This Solution is very better!!!

Answer (score 9):

You can get the desired result in two steps:

```
d1 = TransformedDistribution[x1^2 + x2^2, 
      {Distributed[x1, NormalDistribution[0, σ]], 
       Distributed[x2, NormalDistribution[0, σ]]}]
(* ExponentialDistribution[1/(2 σ^2)] *)

d2 = TransformedDistribution[Sqrt[z], Distributed[z, d1]]
(* RayleighDistribution[σ] *)

PDF[d2,r]
```

> $\begin{cases}
>  \frac{r e^{-\frac{r^2}{2 \sigma ^2}}}{\sigma ^2} & r>0 \\
>  0 & \text{True}
> \end{cases}$

You can also fold the two steps into a single step:

```
With[{d1 =TransformedDistribution[x1^2 + x2^2, 
     {Distributed[x1, NormalDistribution[0, σ]], 
      Distributed[x2, NormalDistribution[0, σ]]}]}, 
TransformedDistribution[Sqrt[z], Distributed[z, d1]]]
(*  RayleighDistribution[σ] *)
```

**Update:** The results above are obtained in Version 9.0.1.0. As noted by @m0nhawk in the comments, in version 10, `TransformedDistribution[Sqrt[z], Distributed[z, d1]]` gives the result

```
WeibullDistribution[2, Sqrt[2] σ]
```

which is equivalent to `RayleighDistribution[σ]`:

```
PDF[WeibullDistribution[2, Sqrt[2] σ], r] == PDF[d2, r]
(* True *)
```

Comment: I'm getting `WeibullDistribution[2, Sqrt[2]/Sqrt[1/\[Sigma]^2]]` for `d2`. *Mathematica* 10.1.

Comment: @m0nhawk, interesting. I am using v9.0.1.0. Btw, `WeibullDistribution[2, Sqrt[2] σ]` _is_ equivalent to `RayleighDistribution[σ]`.

Comment: Yeah, I know, I just provide a usefull information that other *Mathematica* version have other output.

Comment: @m0nhawk, thank you. Updated with a note on the version 10 output.

Comment: Mathematica Should do this Automatically but didn't!
is This a Bug?

Comment: @Hamid, thank you for the accept. I agree with you mma have made all of us expect to get a lot of symbolic magic _automatically_; but... not sure if we can call it a bug:)

Comment: is there any possibility to Drive the Distribution of Rice Formula Based on two normal distribution and one of them with a nonzero Mean, Can You help me about that?

Comment: @Hamid, i can't think of a way off the top of my head, but it should be possible. I suggest to post it as a new question so that you get a better chance for faster/better answers/suggestions.

Comment: Hamid, if this were my question I would accept @Simon's answer.